# Direct connecting 5v relay interface board to usb

Tags: usb, relay

I'm absolutely noob in electronics but I have [this relay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-1-Channel-5V-Relay-Module-Shield-for-Arduino-ARM-PIC-AVR-DSP-SRD-05VDC-SLC-/251195948214) and I want to connect it to USB.
When PC switches on usb VCC has +5v. Can I connect USB VCC to Relay Board "VCC" and "IN" wires to open relay (and GND to GND)? I need open relay when PC switches on and close relay when it switches off.

**upd:**
1-Channel Relay interface board info:

- Each one needs 15-20mA Driver Current
- Equiped with high-current relay : DC30V 10A AC250V 10A
- Standard interface that can be controlled directly by microcontroller (Arduino , 8051, AVR, PIC, DSP, ARM)

[image]

Comment: As it turned out my motherboard does not turn off USB power when switching off the PC. I eventually used a 5 volt power supply output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module uses 15-20mA of current from the USB's 5V, which is safe. If you want the relay to switch on when power is applied, connect the input to ground. (You don't want the relay to switch off when power is applied, because then it will always be off.) Notice that the relay's contacts are switchover, so you can use it either as normally-open or normally-closed.

You can save some power if you disconnect the power indication LED (at the right on the schematic.)

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any reason why not. The board draws a few tens of milliamps and has diode protection for the relay coil.

Strictly speaking, I believe the USB specification requires that USB devices negotiate with the host for power usage. In practice I believe non-compliant devices can usually draw up to 100 mA,

I would try it with a cheap powered USB hub first.